# Is it a Must to Validate Global Codes?

Tags: html, css, validation, w3c-validation

There are some global codes which are not valid according to w3c standards for example we can consider YouTube embed code or Facebook plugins. In such cases, what shall we do?

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6mXNg9HSyYo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**What you suggest me to do in such cases? To edit the codes to ensure w3c validation or to just leave these when my entire website is w3c validated?**

Best Regards,
Touhid

Comment: It was unacceptable to edit the question to something completely different. There was even an accepted answer to the original question. If you have a new question, post it as a new question, and leave the original question with its answers intact, so that people with similar problems can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only validation error given for this (when checking in HTML5) is:

> The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Basically this means that `frameborder` is no longer supported in HTML5 (and can be achieved through CSS). The reason this is still included, however, is because not all browsers have HTML5 support - so this works as a fall-back.

You shouldn't have any problems removing that attribute if you want your site to pass all validation tests, but it's very unlikely that any issues will ever arise from leaving that attribute there.

Comment: Thanks James for the answer. What do you suggest me? To add the frameborder using css or just to leave it?

Comment: Should be okay just to leave it. :)

Comment: The HTML5 drafts *require* browsers to support `frameborder` and simultaneously tell authors not to use it, but authors can ignore this if they like. No browser has HTML5 support, and HTML5 is still work in progress, and HTML5 validators are experimental software. On the practical side, there is no reason to remove the attribute if you want to have the effect it creates.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela `frameborder` [isn't mentioned](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) in the HTML5 specification. Where are you getting that from?

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#conformance-classes and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#attributes-for-embedded-content-and-images

Comment: In that case, what was wrong with my answer then? My answer states that the attribute is obsolete, and also that it works as a fall-back - which is basically what those parts of the spec state.

Comment: The statement “is no longer supported in HTML5” is in contradiction with the requirement on support in HTML5 drafts, as already explained.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The following twitter code is invalid according to w3c. How can I fix it?

'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=nutripak&amp;include_rts=true&amp;count=5&amp;callback=twitterCallback2" target="_blank"></script>' 

The error is happening because of blank attribute. But this code is generated by twitter.

Comment: @TouhidRahman, post a new question if you have problems different from the one asked here. Do not use comments for attempts at discussing other question, and foremost do *not* edit the question to something completely different.